# Java WebLookAndFeel doesn't shows Column Control Popup Menu of a JXTable

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jxtable

I have an issue with Java WebLookAndFeel class. I have an application made in Java Swing in which I set the look and feel using it. Inside the app, I have a button that launches a new JDialog that contains a JXTable inside a JScrollBar. The problem is that I need to show the column control menu of the JXTable, and that doesn't happen when the table is loaded in a new JDialog or JFrame. I need this:

[image]

and I've got this:

[image]

This is the function that I call to set the UI look and feel. If I don't call this, the column control popup menu of the JXTable shows properly, otherwise doesn't shows. Any suggestion? Thanks!

```
public static void setWebLookAndFeel ()
{
    try
    {
        WebLookAndFeel webLookAndFeel = new WebLookAndFeel();
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(webLookAndFeel);
        
        UIManager.put("Table.gridColor"       , new Color(0, 0, 0, 4));
        UIManager.put("TableHeader.cellBorder", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));

    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println( e );
    }
```

Comment: Are you doing this `table.setColumnControlVisible(true);` ?

Comment: Yes, I do that. The table works perfectly. If I don't run the method to set the WebLookAndFeel object to the UI, the Control Column Popup menu is visible, but if run it, is not visible..